# How to build release Flutter project using Android Studio

Tags: flutter, android-studio, google-play, release

I cannot build my project using Android Studio. I create project using console, then edit at VSCode. Now I open it at Android Studio and I cannot build release. Why this command `Build bundles` (green arrow) is not available?
[image]

Comment: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flutter project consist of subprojects:

- /MyProject

  - /iOS - (iOS subproject)
  - /android - (android subproject)

When I open project "MyProject" I see:
[image]

But when I open android submodule/subproject "MyProject/android" I see another options under "Build":

[image]

So solution is:
**If You want build Android package for Google Play store, You must open in IDE Android submodule, for example solder `/MyProject/android`**

Case with Xcode, iOS and AppStore package looks similar - it is important to open `iOS` submodule, not whole `MyProject`.

Answer (score 2):

Try to hover on Flutter name in that list or click on arrow button then build apk then create your .apk file

Or run below command

```
flutter build apk --release
```

See below image:

[image]

See your apk here-> `directory:\your_project_name\build\app\outputs\flutter-apk`

Answer (score 0):

Open The Android Studio and also open your project.

First you click the build->Flutter->build APK.

Second you get the massage path.

Third you get the build folder then you click the
build->app->outputs->flutter-apk->app-release.apk.

You can see the image for the 3 steps to Build Apk:
[image]